# Access of private field of another object in copy constructors - Really a problem?

Tags: java, encapsulation

In my Java application I have some copy-constructors like this

```
public MyClass(MyClass src) {
    this.field1 = src.field1;
    this.field2 = src.field2;
    this.field3 = src.field3;
...
}
```

Now Netbeans 6.9 warns about this and I wonder what is wrong with this code?

My concerns:

- Using the getters might introduce unwanted side-effects. The new object might no longer be considered a copy of the original.
- If it is recommended using the getters, wouldn't it be more consistent if one would use setters for the new instance as well?

**EDIT:** The actual warning is "Access of private field of another object" and the only available action Netbeans offers is adding a `@SuppressWarnings("AccessingNonPublicFieldOfAnotherObject")`

My code is actually as trivial as the given example.

Comment: What is the warning from Netbeans?

Comment: I can only speculate on the reason: Some people think that `private` means that only the current *object* can access the field (while in reality other objects of the same class can also access the field). Maybe this warning is meant as a reminder that this is actually possible and to prevent people from doing it accidentally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no problem with the code. In fact, I share your concerns and would prefer to not use getters.

What exactly is the warning you get? Maybe it is related to something you are not showing us?

**Update:** Seems Netbeans is really complaining about just that. That is a rather controversial warning to ship with an IDE, I would think.

Comment: Absolutely. The concept of private is for *private to the class implementation*, in my view. A copy constructor is part of the class implementation and can do what it likes with private data.

Comment: Such a copy is a problem if the fields are not primitive, but fields of which the contents can change.Even if that's wanted you can still get concurrency issues.

Comment: @extraneon: That seems to be outside of the scope of the warning. Wrapping things into getters is also not going to make a difference there.

Comment: After doing some further research I agree. I'll disable this warning, as the only possible occurrences known to me (copy constructors and `equals`) are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6):

It reminds me of the discussion **ADT** vs. **Object**.

ADT can access the internal state of other instance of the ADT. The object philosophy would prevent that and enforce access through getter/setter to ensure **representation independence**.

It's been a deliberated choice that instances variable in Java are **class-private**, not **object-private** (In the later case only `this.privateInstVar` is allowed, not `obj.privateInstVar`).

This has both strength and weaknesses. It's espcially handy when it comes to **cloning** and **equality**. On the other hand it can be misused and **break encapsulation**.

It's almost a philosophical debate. But IMHO, what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why NetBeans warns, but you are effectively making a *shallow* copy. Your copy shares field1, field2 and field3 with src and as such a modification of field3, say, a List, will reflect in the original.

```
private List field1;

public MyClass(MyClass src) {
    this.field1 = src.field1;
    this.field2 = src.field2;
    this.field3 = src.field3;

    field1.add(new Object()); // field1 of src also modified
...
}
```

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of mutable types. But in this case I'm only copying `int` and `String` types

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the class could provide a shallow copy method which knows which data to return in a copied object. If needed, you could provide a deep-copy too.

```
public MyClass shallowCopy() {
  MyClass aCopy = new MyClass();
  aCopy.field1 = this.field1;
  aCopy.field2 = this.field2;
  aCopy.field3 = this.field3;
}
```

Comment: This gives the exact same warning.